# Pandas read_excel fails if "index_col" and "parse_cols" are set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Excel worksheet that I'm using as part of an Coursera course with the following structure:

[image]

I'm trying to create a pandas dateframe using the following code where I set the index_col=4 and parse_cols=[4,6] and it fails.

```
def get_recession_start():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession start time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3'''
    df1 = pandas.read_excel('gdplev.xls',
                            header=None,
                            skiprows=220,
                            index_col=4,
                            names=['Quarter', 'GDP'],
                            parse_cols=[4,6])
    return df1

get_recession_start()
```

Any reason why I cant select specific columns to build a dataframe and set one of them to be the index?

The error message that I'm receiveing is:

[image]

I'm using Python 3 and Pandas 0.18.1

Corrected thanks to the answers in the post.

```
def get_recession_start():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession start time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3'''
    df1 = pd.read_excel('gdplev.xls',
                            header=None,
                            skiprows=220,
                            index_col=0,
                            names=['GDP'],
                            parse_cols=[4,6])
    df1.index.name = 'Quarter'
    return df1

print(get_recession_start())
```

The output is Quater as index and GDP as column

```
             GDP
Quarter         
2000q1   12359.1
2000q2   12592.5
2000q3   12607.7
2000q4   12679.3
2001q1   12643.3
```

Comment: If you include the sample excel file it can be tested. And avoid attaching images as far as possible. Always post errors, code, sample files, sample df.head() as text.

Comment: Can you test the code I have provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `index_col` to `0`

```
 df1 = pandas.read_excel('gdplev.xls', header=None, skiprows=220, index_col=0,  names=['Quarter', 'GDP'], parse_cols=[4,6])
 print df1.index
```

Comment: Hi @Shijo. The index column is at position 4, and I'm trying to select columns 4 and 6 to build the dataframe, where 4 will be the index and 6 the values column.

Comment: Hi @PeterWilson check the index set to dataframe , you will see that its set to first column of data frame , which is column E in your excel sheet

Comment: HI @Shijo, you were correct, what I was getting wrong was assuming the names variable would set the index name to Quarter.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to include the index column also in parse_cols. Since you have provided `names=['Quarter', 'GDP']`, It is expecting 2 more columns apart from the index column. You can use `parse_cols=[4,5,6]` or `parse_cols=range(4,7)`

Test this:

```
def get_recession_start():
    '''Returns the year and quarter of the recession start time as a 
    string value in a format such as 2005q3'''
    df1 = pandas.read_excel('gdplev.xls',
                            header=None,
                            skiprows=220,
                            index_col=0,
                            names=['Quarter', 'GDP'],
                            parse_cols=[4,5,6])
    return df1

print(get_recession_start())
```

Comment: Thanks @MYGz i was trying to name the index at the same time with the names variable, didn't realise it was for the columns only.

Comment: @PeterWilson If that solved your problem then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: For new version of pandas, we should use `usecols` instead of `parse_cols`.